# drawLineGraphWithContext not working

Tags: ios, draw, lines

I try to build my project with [topic](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-graph-with-quartz-2d-part-3/) and `drawLineGraphWithContext` making sure that it goes before the `drawRect`.

And I try to run it. It's not working. The lines I want to show hide.
I'm a new developer in iOS, so I have more mistake!

Comment: Please edit your question and post the relevant code. And please tell us which part of your code doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

drawLineGraphWithContext should be called in drawRect method to make it works.